# How to use fake data to test RecyclerView?

Tags: android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I made my DataFakeGenerator to creat some fake datas to test my Recycelerview , but when i want to use it in one of my Fragments i have an error.
my error is in this line:

PostAdapter postAdapter = new PostAdapter(DataFakeGenerator.getData(this));

it says that i can not use "this",so what statement can i use in this parentheses?

here is my Fragment :

```
public class Frag_joke extends Fragment {


public  static Fragment instance(){
    Fragment fragment = new Frag_joke();
    return fragment;
}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    ViewGroup layout = (ViewGroup)inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag_joke,null);
    RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView)layout.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    PostAdapter postAdapter = new PostAdapter(DataFakeGenerator.getData(this));
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this.getActivity()));
    recyclerView.setAdapter(postAdapter);

   return layout;

}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
}}
```

here is my DataFakeGenerator :

```
public class DataFakeGenerator {
public static List<Post> getData(){
    List<Post> posts= new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i=0;i<=6;i++){
        Post post= new Post();
        post.setId(i);
        post.setContent("sample text");
        posts.add(post);
    }

    return posts;
}}
```

and here is my PostAdapter:

```
public class PostAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PostAdapter.PostViewHolder>{


private Context context;
private List<Post> posts;

public PostAdapter(Context context, List<Post>posts){

    this.context = context;
    this.posts = posts;
}

@Override
public PostViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.layout_post,parent,false);
    return new PostViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(PostViewHolder holder, int position) {

    Post post=posts.get(position);
    holder.content.setText(post.getContent());
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return posts.size();
}

public class PostViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{


    private TextView content;

    public PostViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        content=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.post_content);
    }}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably confused with your implementation. `DataFakeGenerator.getData()` does not need any parameter. It's your adapter constructor that has 2.

To create your adapter you can use the following instead:
`PostAdapter postAdapter = new PostAdapter(getContext(), DataFakeGenerator.getData());`

PS: `this` wouldn't work with the adapter creation (if that's the code you are actually trying to use), as the `Fragment` is not a context (but the Activity is, which is why you can access it with `getContext()` from the fragment

Comment: wow! that works, i didn't know "this" doesn't work for fragment, thanks, you really saved me

Answer (score 1):

You can set preview on any cardview if you've. Let's you have a cardview name item_emergency_contact then, you can use *tools:listitem="@layout/your_card_view"*

```
            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/contacts_recyclerView_emergency"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
            tools:listitem="@layout/item_emergency_contact"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/add_emergency_contacts" />
```